# Локализация приложения qt

Tags: qt, qt5, локализация

Есть приложение Qt, хотелось бы сделать так, чтобы оно работало на двух языках - русском и английском. Все, что вроде бы нужно, я уже сделал - `tr()` для текста, файл перевода в Linguist тоже есть.
В данный момент пытаюсь вызвать перевод так:

```
QTranslator translator;  
translator.load("translation_"+QLocale::system().name());  
qApp->installTranslator(&translator);
```

Однако ничего не меняется, все так же, как и в исходниках
Что я делаю не так? Что надо изменить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Доброго времени суток!

Ваша проблема в том, что Вы пытаетесь использовать для перевода не тот файл: Вам нужно использовать файл *.qm - это файл который получается после работы Qt Linguist)

Файлы с раширением *.ts - это только разметка (в формате XML), которую понимает Qt Linguist для того чтобы сгенерировать уже сам* .qm файл перевода в **двоичном виде** и иммено qm файлы используются `QTranslator`)

Собственно от способа загрузки ничего не зависит - можете загружать из файла на жестком диске, можете из ресурсов - как Вам больше нравиться)

Успехов!

Answer (score 0):

Время жизни объекта translator должно быть не меньше времени использования данного языка. Т.е. сделайте его static, например или создайте в куче перед первым использованием

Comment: Перед первым использованием - это в `main.cpp` после создания объекта `QApplication`?

Comment: Как вариант

Comment: Я так и сделал, однако ничего не изменилось. Я даже указываю само имя файла перевода, ничего не меняется

Comment: Скорее всего не находит файл перевода. Он в ресурсах?

Comment: Добавил в ресурсы (создал в ресурсах префикс `/lang`, туда добавил `translation_ru.ts`), в исходниках теперь вызываю так: `translator.load(":/lang/translation_ru.ts");`. Все равно все также. Может ли быть проблема в самом `installTranslator`?